# How to add cookie in cross domain xhr call from client?

Tags: javascript, cookies

For example if I have a cookie from domain `A` and my javascript client code is in domain `B`. Does browser auto pass the cookie of domain `A` to the request when I do an ajax request from domain `B` to domain `A`?

Is there a setting I should add to set the cookie? It seems like my javascript client does not have access to domain `A` cookies.

For reference I am using this library https://github.com/naugtur/xhr

Answer (score 0):

Use `withCredentials:true`.

This allows the cookies from remote domain to be passed back and forth assuming the correct access control headers are set at remote end point to allow *"withCredentials"*

Reference: [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `withCredentials` setting of your XHR library.

So:

```
var xhr = require("xhr")

xhr({
    withCredentials: true, // <--- this!
    method: "post",
    body: someJSONString,
    uri: "/foo",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}, function (err, resp, body) {
    // check resp.statusCode
})
```